# Windows XP and IE8 javascript won't work even though Enable Active Scripting is enabled

Tags: windows-xp, javascript

I have a Windows XP machine on our LAN, origianlly running IE7 and now IE8, javascript won't work even though Enable Active Scripting is enabled. I've disabled the Anti-Virus with no luck. Other PCs are fine. Any suggestions on what would cause this?

Comment: Have you disabled/uninstalled any addons/toolbars/extensions/accelerators etc ? They can cause issues, strange ones with upgraded versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try lowering the security level on IE8 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your IE settings with Service->Additional-> Reset button.

Comment: I have tried this with no luck.

Comment: try to see with Sysinternals Autoruns which dll modules loaded as BHO, explorer additions and network protocols then